# Проблема с получением конфигурации Realm в Android

Tags: java, android, realm

Когда питаюсь что то записать в Realm вылетает ошибка.
Делал все по туториале

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A non-null RealmConfiguration must be provided`

код из Application:

```
public class App extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Realm.init(this);
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(new RealmConfiguration
            .Builder()
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
            .modules(new ShopingListModule())
            .build());
}}
```

Вылетает на строке в презентере когда хочу получить или записать что то в базу :

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration());
```

В интернете информации не нашел. Кто сталкивался как решали?

Comment: Realm.getDefaultInstance() разве не аналогичный вызов? Ну кстати не имеет значения, надо логировать, и смотреть в какой момент конфиги труться, мб deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded() затирает?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()  не затирает уже пробовал убирать.
А где логи то ставить? сетаю конфигурацию в Application  перехожу в другие активити и там записать пытаюсь и ошибка в первой при записи строке

Comment: да просто продебажьте, Watcher поставьте на config, и смотрите когда он null становится